# Why isn't ubuntu checking the correct directory in the $PATH variable?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to run a program `redis-cli`

```
$ ls -lh /usr/local/bin/ | grep redis
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.2M Mar 24 19:49 redis-cli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5.6M Mar 24 19:49 redis-server

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

If the program `redis-cli` exists in the directory `/usr/local/bin` and that directory is in my path variable, why do I get the following error?

```
$ redis-cli
-bash: /usr/bin/redis-cli: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT**

```
$ /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>

$ redis-cli
-bash: /usr/bin/redis-cli: No such file or directory

$ file /usr/local/bin/redis-cli
/usr/local/bin/redis-cli: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x3715af7983c534d902d8dc627f9b0f1b4c8b8e80, not stripped
```

Comment: What shell are you using? (it would be `bash` unless you changed it)

Comment: I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and am using bash, `$ echo $0` -bash.  This is pretty much a fresh install I launched from a ubuntu 12.04 AMI http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/

Comment: Can you also post `file $(which -a redis-cli)`?

Comment: `file $(which -a redis-cli)
/usr/local/bin/redis-cli: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x3715af7983c534d902d8dc627f9b0f1b4c8b8e80, not stripped`

Comment: ... and file `/usr/bin/redis-cli` exists? Please post `file /usr/bin/redis-cli` and `uname -a`.

Comment: There is no file `/usr/bin/redis-cli` and I'm using ubuntu 12.04.  However my $PATH variable specifies the directory `/usr/local/bin` which contains `redis-cli`

Comment: This error is typical when you f.e. use a 32bit binary on a 64bit system, or if a shared library is missing. But still it's a little strange that `/usr/bin/redis-cli` doesn't exist. Can you make a simple script (see http://paste.ubuntu.com/5644521/), name it say `test.sh`, run it as `strace -o /tmp/s.log ./test.sh`, and if you see the same error again, post the log `/tmp/s.log` somewhere?

Comment: I didn't see the error when I ran your test script and was able to get into the redis-cli.  Thanks for your help.  I'm just going to add `redis-cli` to the directory `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 3):

Chances are there used to be a redis-cli in /usr/bin/redis-cli which has now been deleted.

Bash maintains an internal hash of executables on your path which hasn't been updated. If you encounter this problem again, rehash it and it will work.

```
hash redis-cli
```

Comment: This is what happens to me, and as this can easily happen: Dear Reader, this is probably what happens to you!

Answer (score 0):

It kind of looks like you have an alias or a shell function with that name; I believe both of those would bypass your $PATH and be hidden from 'which'.

To check for an alias:

```
alias redis-cli
```

To delete an alias if you find one:

```
unalias redis-cli
```

To check for a function:

```
declare -f redis-cli
```

To delete a function if you find one:

```
unset -f redis-cli
```

If one of these does turn out to be the problem, then those commands will only help until the end of that terminal session, and you would have to re-run them again next time. You'll want to check your .bashrc and .profile to see if there are any rogue commands in there that mention redis-cli. If that doesn't work, they may be somewhere in /etc.

```
grep redis-cli /etc
```